# Gem::InstallError: The 'nio4r' native gem requires installed build tools

Tags: ruby, windows-10, ruby-development-kit

I am trying to run `bundle install` and I get the following error message (screenshots attached):

```
Gem::InstallError: The 'nio4r' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'

An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

[image: When the installation fails]

So then, I run `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` and it installs perfectly as the screenshot below.[image: When the installation succeeds]

The paths I have set is as follows:
[image: The paths screenshots]

Comment: Do you have the DevKit installed?

Comment: yeah I have it installed.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you try running cmd as admin?

Comment: @whodini9 Nope, no difference. It only stops during `nio4r`. But if I install it just that, then it installs with no problem

Comment: what do you get when you do ruby -v on command-line

Comment: I get the version number: `2.3.3`. It's a 64-bit Ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow or another you're interacting with two different installations of Ruby and the on later in the `PATH` has Bundler installed.

Once you install the Devkit the `must install Devkit` message is completely removed from the installation.

Try running `where.exe bundle` to see where the Bundler executables are at, then run `where.exe gem` to see where your RubyGem executables are and compare.

If you have two different `gem` executable locations then you probably could just use `gem install bundler` to quickly fix the problem.

Comment: I get the following: `C:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.2.6-0\ruby\bin\bundle
C:\Bitnami\rubystack-2.2.6-0\ruby\bin\bundle.bat`

Comment: Is that where you installed the Ruby you want to use? I'll add more to the answer to clarify what you need to check.

Comment: Then you got rid of the problem when you uninstalled and reinstalled. But, it's impossible to have the `Temporarily enhancing PATH` message and the `Need to install DevKit` message in the same installation. =)

Answer (score 1):

I removed the 64-bit and installed the 32-bit Ruby, and it worked fine. Although I had the `64-bit` DevKit, it worked without me having to install the 32-bit Devkit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

Manually downloading the latest .gem file from [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/downloads/nio4r-2.0.0.gem).
Install it using `gem install nio4r-x.x.x.gem`

Comment: I've tried installing it manually, it worked. Then when I go with `bundle install` again, it fails

Comment: @SuthanBala are you installing the gem in same gemset? please specify version of installed `nio4r` in Gemfile.

Comment: Yes, I installed the same version that failed. I've installed `1.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I download DEVELOPMENT KIT from [rubby website](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), and followed the instruction at [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit). After installing DevKit, the issue was resolved. My OS was Win64X and I installed Ruby-2.3.3-64X accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> download newer version of ruby [(download from official site)](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and then try to install rail, your problem will be solve.